# Need help understanding create_function() and regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-replace-callback, create-function

After allot of searching around SO and other forums also stumbling over various php function documentation, I tried to edit a function that I found on here(converts URLs to clickable links) so it will also handle embedded video, unfortunately my skill set is poor and I believe I don't fully understand `create_function()` to be successful at this.

So here's my scrambled egg code:

```
private function _check4Links($text){
    $pattern  = '#\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))#';
    $callback = create_function('$matches', '
       $url       = array_shift($matches);
       $url_parts = parse_url($url);

       if(preg_match("%(?:youtube\.com/(?:user/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i", $url, $match)){
            return sprintf(\'<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="400" height="244" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/\'.$match[1].\'" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>\', $url, $text);
       }else{

            $text = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
            $text = preg_replace("/^www./", "", $text);

            $last = -(strlen(strrchr($text, "/"))) + 1;
            if ($last < 0) {
               $text = substr($text, 0, $last) . "&hellip;";
            }

            return sprintf(\'<a target="_blank"rel="nofollow" href="%s">%s</a>\', $url, $text);
       }');

    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $text);
}
```

I should also mention that i'm **not** looking for someone to just show me the correct code, I'm looking for someone to explain to me why my code is not working and what i am doing wrong. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Why are you using lambda-function for this? Can't see any dynamic generated code inside it. I think that it'll be much easier to debug with normal function. Moreover, you don't have any placeholders for video `sprintf()`. That's not an error though.

Comment: @WASD42 Well that's just what they were using so I just tried to edit it as little as possible trying to keep most of the code intact. Would you suggest I do it normally?

Comment: Yes, I will :) it seems that there is an unclosed quote (") in your regexp.

Comment: @WASD42, if that quote is in `preg_match()`, then it is rather unescaped than unclosed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fix:

```
<?php
function _check4Links($text){
    $pattern  = '#\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))#';

    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'fnc', $text);
}

function fnc($matches) {
    $url       = array_shift($matches);
    $url_parts = parse_url($url);

    if(preg_match("%(?:youtube\.com/(?:user/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^\"&?/ ]{11})%i", $url, $match)){
          return '<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="400" height="244" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$match[1].'" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>';
    } else {

        $text = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
        $text = preg_replace("/^www./", "", $text);

        $last = -(strlen(strrchr($text, "/"))) + 1;
        if ($last < 0) {
            $text = substr($text, 0, $last) . "&hellip;";
        }

        return sprintf('<a target="_blank"rel="nofollow" href="%s">%s</a>', $url, $text);
        }
    }

$txt = <<<TXT
Let's do some tests!
http://www.google.com
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L25R4DR79mU
TXT;

echo _check4Links($txt);
?>
```

The output is:

```
Let's do some tests!
<a target="_blank"rel="nofollow" href="http://www.google.com">google.com</a>
<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="400" height="244" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L25R4DR79mU" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I will say that I had to edit `5: return preg_replace_callback($pattern, array($this, 'fnc'), $text);` but that is no fault of yours. Thank you again.

Comment: Of course, because in your case it is a class method, while in my example it is a stand-alone function :) You are welcome!

Comment: I would add a space between `target="_blank"` and `rel="nofollow"`.